# How do I override an abstract method in java?

Tags: java

The purpose of this code is to find the amount of items one wishes to buy, the price of those items, and what the sale currently is. For a buy three get one free sale, it would look something like

1 items at 5.0; discount is 0

2 items at 5.0; discount is 0

3 items at 5.0; discount is 5.0

4 items at 5.0; discount is 5.0

The class extends an abstract class whose abstract method is computeDiscount()

However, I have no idea how to make this method function, because it won't except it as static, but if the method isn't static then I can't use it in my code!

I have no idea what to do, and I desperately need help

```java
package homeFolder;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BuyNItemsGetOneFree extends DiscountPolicy{

        static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        static double itemCost;
        static int count = count();
        static int n = getN();
        static double discount = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            itemCost = itemCost();

            for(int i = 1; i <= count; i ++) {

                discount = computeDiscount(i, itemCost);

                System.out.println(i + " items at " + itemCost +
                                    "; discount is " + discount);

            }

        }

        public static double itemCost() {

            System.out.print("Enter the cost of the item: ");
            itemCost = input.nextDouble();

            return itemCost;

        }

        public static int count() {

            System.out.print("How many items are you going to buy: ");
            count = input.nextInt();

            return count;

        }

        public static int getN() {

            System.out.print("How many items must you buy till you got one free? ");
            n = input.nextInt();

            return n;

        }

        public double computeDiscount(int count, double itemCost) {

            double discount = 0;

            if((count % n) == 0)
                discount += itemCost;

            return discount;

        }
    }
```

Comment: This should raise an error. Your main needs to be `public static void main` (note the `static`). If you really aren't getting an error, you must have a legitimate `main` somewhere else that doesn't do anything, and it's being run instead of this.

Comment: The parent method has no public static void main and changing the main method to some other name, and ditching (System[] args) yields no results

Comment: @SpencerJackson You don't need a proper main because of a base class, you need a proper main because every program requires a `public static void main`. Just add `static` like I said.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do anything with [abstraction](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_abstract.asp), you can't be using static methods. Here, it's best to use instance variables combined with a factory method to do all the initilization action.

```
package homeFolder;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BuyNItemsGetOneFree extends DiscountPolicy {

    // Below are your fields, or instance variables. Notice the lack of static.
    final double itemCost;
    final int count;
    final int n;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Now you have an instance to work with.
        BuyNItemsGetOneFree sale = newInstance();

        for(int i = 1; i <= sale.count; i ++) {

            double discount = sale.computeDiscount(i, itemCost);

            System.out.println(i + " items at " + sale.itemCost +
                                "; discount is " + discount);

        }

    }

    // Only the factory method can access this.
    private BuyNItemsGetOneFree (double itemCost, int count, int n) {
        this.itemCost = itemCost;
        this.count = count;
        this.n = n;
    }

    public static BuyNItemsGetOneFree newInstance() {

        // The scanner really only needs to be used here.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Initilizes itemCost
        System.out.print("Enter the cost of the item: ");
        double itemCost = input.nextDouble();

        // Initilizes count
        System.out.print("How many items are you going to buy: ");
        int count = input.nextInt();

        // Initilizes n
        System.out.print("How many items must you buy till you got one free? ");
        int n = input.nextInt();

        // Constructs and returns
        return new BuyNItemsGetOneFree(itemCost, count, n);
    }

    @Override // Always add this when overriding a method.
    public double computeDiscount(int count, double itemCost) {

        double discount = 0;

        if((count % n) == 0)
            discount += itemCost;

        return discount;
    }
}
```

If you want to go a step further, there is no need for the parameters in `computeDiscount` as they are (from what I see) just going to reference fields already able to be used.

Answer (score -1):

Spencer make all your methods static and also your main method is missing static.
it should be something like this `public static void main(String [] args)`

Comment: Changing all methods to static is probably the wrong thing to do.  The question and the existing code makes it clear that he has been told to override `computeDiscount`.  You can't do that by declaring it as `static`.

Comment: But he made changes to the question. It seems my answer is not right anymore. He was missing some stuff when I answered it.

Comment: I looked at the original version of the question.  It also makes it clear that the method from the abstract superclass needs to be overridden.